# How to use regular expression match "in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, expression

For example , the following is the source I want match:

```
<div class="cont">
```

I use

```
<div\s+class\=\"cont\">
```

But it doesn't work , if I modify the expression like

```
<div\s+class\=.*?cont.*?>
```

Now , it can give me the result I want .

So I think , the problem should be in " this character.

Following is the code I use in iOS , it can works for some other regular expression:

```
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:reg options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:resultStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [resultStr length])];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {

        NSRange matchRange = [match range];

        NSString *tagString = [resultStr substringWithRange:matchRange];

        [resultArr addObject:tagString];

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have `"` in your input string?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match HTML with regular expressions. It is definitely very troublesome, since HTML you receive can be all uppercase, single quotes may be used instead of double or be missing, etc.

That said, if you really need a regex solution, I'd recommend to account for any number of attributes before `class=cont` and allow any attribute value delimiters:

```
NSString *pattern = @"<div\\b[^<]*class=[\"']?cont\\b[^<]*>";
```

Here, I am using `\b` to match a word boundary, `[^<]*` checks for any other attributes before `class`, `["']?` allows either a single or double quotation mark or nothing, then `\b` makes sure `cont` is followed by a non-word character, and `[^<]*` checks for any other attributes before final `>`.

Also, `\"` is escaped once as it is a C string delimiter and `\\b` is escaped twice to make sure we pass `\b` to the regex engine.

Sample code at [CodingGround](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMeVEwNjVXZ05halk):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Foundation/NSTextCheckingResult.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *pattern = @"<div\\b[^<]*class=[\"']?cont\\b[^<]*>";
    NSString *string = @"<div class=\"cont\">";
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:range];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
       NSRange matchRange = [match range];
       NSString *m = [string substringWithRange:matchRange];
       NSLog(@"Matched string: %@", m);
    }

   [pool drain];
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for waiting so long . I mean  I can't escaped the character " , such as  , I used the regular expression like    \"\w+\"     for  matching the string    "hello"         , It doesn't work .    Or I match the character " with \" , It still doesn't work.

Comment: You should have used `\"\\w+\"` as the regex escapes (those that will be treated by the regex engine as special signals for shorthand classes, etc) must be *doubled*. See a [working demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMFBGaThjMjZTdmM) for the `"hello"` string with `\"\\w+\"` regex.

Comment: Do you want to say you are trying to match `\"` string literal? But `@"\"hello\""` C string is actually `"hello"`, not `\"hello\"`. There are no escapes. Also, you are using `\\w`, not `\\w+`, and thus you are matching *only 1* alphanumeric character, and your regex won't match `"hello"` for sure.

Comment: Yes , It works ,thank you . If I want to match the string `divName` in `<div class="hello" id="world" name="divName">` , I write the regular expression like `(?<=<div.*?name\=\").*?(?=\")`   , It doesn't work.  It seems to be inside the assertions can't use regular expression.

Comment: You are trying to use a variable-width look-behind, and it is not available in [Objective C regex syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html): *The length of possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no * or + operators.)*. You need to use capturing groups instead. Here is [a working example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_objective-c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZnNsQU1kOUJfTE0).

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the code:

```
NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
```